# Insert into postgresql jsonb field

Tags: sql, postgresql, django-orm

Want to perform a raw SQL insert into a json field that already got data in it:

Here's the data in database

```
{
 "clock_in": "2021-08-13T01:15:25.085Z", 
 "clock_out": "2021-08-12T18:15:29.437-07:00", 
 "hours": 5.30, 
 "message": "Good job."
}
```

This is what I tried but got syntax error near WHERE.

```
    def insert_data(data, pk):
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(
                '''INSERT INTO employee (time_log) values (%s)
                WHERE user =%s''', [data, pk]
            )
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what is the type of `data`,if it is object you should convert it to json string

Comment: It's already converted in using cls=DjangoJSONEncoder

Comment: A) `cls=DjangoJSONEncoder` is not shown anywhere in your example, so add the full code of what you are doing to your question. B) You are working with a raw query so I'm not sure A) applies anyway. C) Add the exact error message to your question.  Editorializing just leads to assuming  and we all know where that leads. D) Take a look at [psycopg2 JSON](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#adapt-json)

Comment: Don't worry about python part, I can insert with Django without a problem, what I'm not familiar with is SQL

Comment: Since what you are showing is Python code that is doing the SQL, the Python part is very much in play. Without the actual error message an answer to what you show  is not going to be forthcoming. If you are really interested in just the SQL, then use `psql` and run the query and see what happens.

Comment: I gave the actual error msg: syntax error near WHERE

Comment: I was being stupid. You can't use `WHERE` with an `INSERT` unless you are doing a sub-select from another table to provide the data. So yes it is a syntax error.